# Dynamically add to allowed_domains in a Scrapy spider

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider that starts with a small list of `allowed_domains` at the beginning of the spidering. I need to add more domains dynamically to this whitelist as the spidering continues from within a parser, but the following piece of code does not get that accomplished since subsequent requests are still being filtered. Is there another of updating `allowed_domains` within the parser?

```
class APSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "APSpider"

allowed_domains = ["www.somedomain.com"]

start_urls = [
    "http://www.somedomain.com/list-of-websites",
]

...

def parse(self, response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup( response.body )

    for link_tag in soup.findAll('td',{'class':'half-width'}):
        _website = link_tag.find('a')['href']
        u = urlparse.urlparse(_website)
        self.allowed_domains.append(u.netloc)

        yield Request(url=_website, callback=self.parse_secondary_site)

...
```

Comment: To the OP: just FYI that I don't think the currently accepted answer would really solve your problem. Check the comment left with that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
class APSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "APSpider"

start_urls = [
    "http://www.somedomain.com/list-of-websites",
]

def __init__(self):
    self.allowed_domains = None

def parse(self, response):
    soup = BeautifulSoup( response.body )

    if not self.allowed_domains:
        for link_tag in soup.findAll('td',{'class':'half-width'}):
            _website = link_tag.find('a')['href']
            u = urlparse.urlparse(_website)
            self.allowed_domains.append(u.netloc)

            yield Request(url=_website, callback=self.parse_secondary_site)

    if response.url in self.allowed_domains:
        yield Request(...)

...
```

Comment: *No, this solution shall not work with any existing version (up to 1.0.3) of `scrapy`.* As the `OffsiteMiddleware` reads the content in `allowed_domains` only when initializing the pre-compiled regex object while handling the `spider_opened` signal, values in `allowed_domains` are never accessed later. Thus your solution of updating the value is useless.

Answer (score 10):

(At the very moment when this answer is written, the latest version of `scrapy` is `1.0.3`. This answer shall work for all recent versions of `scrapy`)

As the `OffsiteMiddleware` reads the content in `allowed_domains` only when initializing the precompiled regex object while handling the `spider_opened` signal, values in `allowed_domains` are never accessed later.
Thus simply updating the content of `allowed_domains` shall not solve the problem.

Basically, two steps are required:

1. Update the content of `allowed_domains` according to your actual need.
2. Have the regex cache in `OffsiteMiddleware` refreshed.

Here is the code I use for step #2:

```
# Refresh the regex cache for `allowed_domains`
for mw in self.crawler.engine.scraper.spidermw.middlewares:
    if isinstance(mw, scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware):
        mw.spider_opened(self)
```

The code above is supposed to be invoked inside a response callback, thus `self` here shall be an instance of the spider class.

See also:

- [Source code of `scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware` on GitHub](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py)