# Process url from txt file in python and output the contents of web page also in txt format

Tags: python, web-scraping, spyder

I have a python spider script which only scraps url. But it only takes one url as input. I have a large list of domains input txt file and want to process them all and also save the output to txt file.

Here is my python script

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

DOMAIN = 'google.com'
URL = 'http://%s' % DOMAIN

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = DOMAIN
    allowed_domains = [DOMAIN]
    start_urls = [
        URL
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for url in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
            if not ( url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://') ):
                url= URL + url 
            print url
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

if possible then give verbose mode also.

Answer (score 1):

You may run a script and redirect output to file:

```
scrapy crawl google_parser  > output.txt
```

How to input lines. You may read them from standard input:

**google_parser.py**:

```
import sys
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from scrapy import Spider, Request, spidermiddlewares


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'google_parser'
    allowed_domains = []

    def start_requests(self):
        with sys.stdin as f:
            urls = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
        self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(url).hostname for url in urls]
        # Refresh the regex cache for `allowed_domains`
        # thx to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161815/dynamically-add-to-allowed-domains-in-a-scrapy-spider
        for mw in self.crawler.engine.scraper.spidermw.middlewares:
            if isinstance(mw, spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware):
                mw.spider_opened(self)
        for url in urls:
                yield Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            new_url = response.urljoin(url)
            print(new_url)
            yield Request(new_url)
```

For example:

```
cat urls.txt | scrapy crawl google_parser
```

Output:

```
['http://www.com', 'http://www.me',]
```

Also you can give it file for input directlty:

```
scrapy crawl google_parser < urls.txt
```

And **finally**:

```
scrapy crawl google_parser < urls.txt > output.txt
```

This way gives you very flexible ability to chain programs, like take input list, filter it keeping only some url matching criteria, take N first of them and pass to your program:

```
cat urls.txt | grep '/script.php?' | head -5 | scrapy crawl google_parser > output.txt
```

Comment: ok thats the output solution , but also i have input list  of domains in txt file.

Comment: can you give them w.r.t. to my script ,, i am getting errors .

Comment: actually a lot , when i run even my above script without modification it gives library depreciated error (probably the whole code needs again to re write)

Comment: I've updated script, take a look pls. You may drop it into the scrapy/spiders folder.

Comment: is it working on your end ,,, iam getting depreciated error---------------------------spider.py:2: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
spider.py:11: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: __main__.MySpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spiders.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spiders.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
  class MySpider(BaseSpider):

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. But it's better to do in another way - check the code pls.

Comment: actually your script is not giving any errors but doesnt output results . iam running like ----1. saving your script as spider.py    2. running from terminal as python spider.py (i suppose this should give output) but not working . script exits within a second. (also tested with domain example.com

Comment: hey , my original code is running ,, i am doing it wrong way i t should something like scrapy runspider spider.py >urlsout.txt ,,, but it doesnt take input as you say in DOMAIN parameter as you say in command as input.txt

Comment: Try to run it as a part of scrapy project: `scrapy crawl google_parser`.

Comment: But what for did you fix `DOMAIN` parameter in your code to "google"?  Domains can be  obtained from the same list of `URL`s. Do not forget to refresh a cache.

Comment: here is another error ---- in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: spider1'  ,,,, steps i followed ---1. created a project in scrapy named spidering 2. saved your script as python1.py in spidering folder 3. running command from spideing folder scrapy crawl spider1.py < url.txt   4. then it throws above errors along with lot others.

Comment: scrapy crawl spider1 < url.txt     is also tested.

Comment: also getting these------2017-02-03 11:02:21 [scrapy.core.engine] 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/root/spider1.py", line 20, in start_requests
    yield Request(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:

Comment: Sorry, pal. But I can't help you if you ignore my recommendations. Why do you run it as `scrapy crawl spider1.py` if I wrote to run `scrapy crawl google_parser`? You are doing some hidden things and want me to guess? :)

Comment: Best recommendation: hire a freelance python developer and provide him/her with **all** the information on start. It will require less than 1 hour. And you'll get you task done.

Comment: no problem eugene ,,, anyways i am using just spider1 instead of google_parsor ,, rest codebase in same ,,, thanks for help

Comment: Scrapy is very good for fast spiders development, but there are some subtle moments to know. For example, it takes spider names not from class/file name but from `name` attribute in derived class. That's why it raises `KeyError`. Because renamed file doesn't matter for him, until you change internal name.      Thus your next developer should be provided with all the information and code base. Or start together with him from scratch and follow his recommendations literally. Good Luck!